# How Can i calculate tuple values in python

Tags: python

I have list values which are tuples.

```
list = [ (0,0,1,0,1), (0,0,1,0,1), (0,0,1,0,1) ]
```

How can I achieve that value

```
list = [0,0,3,0,3]
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the two lists?

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: i want to calculate all values of tuple

Comment: What do you mean by calculate?

Comment: It looks like you want to create a list such that the list item with index `i` contains the sum of all the tuple items with index `i`. Is that correct? BTW, `list` is not a good variable name because it shadows the built-in `list` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with `sum`.

```
In [4]: [sum(i) for i in zip(*_list)]
Out[4]: [0, 0, 3, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) the elements of the tuples and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) the result with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
result = map(sum, zip(*lst))
```

Don't forget to tack on a `list(...)` if you're running python3.

Comment: Don't forget that in Python 3  `map` returns an iterator.

Comment: For Python 3 you should add an additional: `out = [r for r in result]`

Comment: @albert Actually, `list(result)` suffices.

Comment: OP never indicated he was using python 3...